# Multiple consecutive dates

Tags: vba, excel

I am working to create a macro that enters ten instances of each date in a month. I've got it to where it goes through the dates, but they all just paste over each other in the first ten cells.

What I need (but sets of ten, not of three):

```
3/1/2013
3/1/2013
3/1/2013
3/2/2013
3/2/2013
3/2/2013
3/3/2013
3/3/2013
3/3/2013
```

Code I have:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim v&, MyDate As Date, Cell As Range

For i = DateValue("3/01/2013") To DateValue("3/31/2013")
    Set Cell = [A1]
    For v = 0 To 9 ' 9 means 10 cells
        Cell.Offset(v, 0).Value = i
    Next v
Next i

End Sub
```

Any suggestions of what I need to use in the code?

Comment: I'm trying to understand this.  So you want a total of 3*31=93 rows?

Comment: It would actually be 10*31=310 rows. I tried to not be redundant with the info while explaining, but forgot to include that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim v&, MyDate As Date, Cell As Range

    Range("A1").Select
    Set Cell = [A1]

    For i = DateValue("3/01/2013") To DateValue("3/31/2013")
        For v = 0 To 9
            ActiveCell.Value = i
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next v
    Next i
End Sub
```

Though 1/3/13 and 31/3/13 work better for me.

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop.

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1") = #3/1/2013#
    Range("A1:A10").DataSeries
End Sub
```

**Updated after comments**

```
Sub test()

    Range("A1") = #3/1/2013#

    For i = 1 To 31
        lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            Range("A1:A" & i * 10) = DateAdd("d", i - 1, #3/1/2013#)
        Else
            Range("A" & lastRow & ":A" & i * 10) = DateAdd("d", i - 1, #3/1/2013#)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is definitely good for future reference for me, but is there a way for me to output it so that each date shows up 10 times in a row, followed with the next date 10 times in a row as well (kinda like the example but with 10 instead of 3)?

Comment: @mnp i have updated the answer to match your requirement. Kindly refresh the page.

Comment: @pnuts Even i agree the requirement was clear but got confused with the example. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Set Cell = [A1]` is inside the outer `For` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered already, but just because it's a little different:

```
    Range("A1:A310").Formula = "=DATE(2013,3,1)+INT(ROW()/10.01)"
    Range("A1:A310").Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

It can even be done in a single step (thanks to some assistance from my colleague Hans):

```
Range("A1:A310").Value = Evaluate("=INDEX(DATE(2013,3,1)+INT(ROW(A1:A310)/10.01),0)")
```